# Get url from query string and load it in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, query-string

I'm designing a simple `ASPX` page which has two `div's`. The first div has static contents. The content in the second i want to be dynamic. I want the user to give URL in query string and that URL i need to show in my second div. So far i have done this.

**Index.aspx:**

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Frames Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function LoadQueryPage() {
            var str = <%= new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Request.QueryString["pagename"]) %>

            $("#siteloader")
            .html('<object data=' + str + '/>');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="min-height: inherit; height: 100px;">
        Farhan S. Mukadam
    </div>
    <div> 
    <object type="text/html" data="http://validator.w3.org/" width="800px" height="600px" style="overflow:auto;border:5px ridge blue">
    </object></div>
</body>
</html>
```

But this is not working. Can someone please help.

Comment: `this is not working`...what is the error...??

Comment: It get's values from Querystring. I don't know exactly. I got this JS code from somewhere.

Comment: where is the implementation of `GetParameterValues`

Comment: This is my second code. Initially i had some other code. I'll post it.

Comment: The error is my 2nd div doesn't open up the URL which i give in my query string.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        var pagename = GetParameterValues('pagename');
        $('#siteloader').load(pagename);
    }); //missing ) here
    function GetParameterValues(param) {
        var regex = new RegExp('(\\?|&)' + param + '=(.*?)()(&|$)')
        return location.href.match(regex)[2];
    }
</script>
```

Also you have not included jQuery in the page

Comment: No success. I can see only the first div. No content in 2nd div.

Comment: @FarhanMukadam any other error in the console

Comment: No error. I can see only 'Farhan S. Mukadam'. When i pass this query string `localhost:60877/Index.aspx?pagename=http://www.asentechll.com`, the 2nd div doesn't show up the site which i specify. Like in my example "www.asentechllc.com". Included jquery as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
function GetRequestParameters(name) {
    if (name = (new RegExp('[?&]' + encodeURIComponent(name) + '=([^&]*)')).exec(location.search))
        return decodeURIComponent(name[1]);
}
```